# Regex PCRE matching on an URL with multiple parameters random values

Tags: regex, pcre, snort, suricata

Sample GET request I want to match on with regex PCRE:

**random.php?blue=value1&green=value2&red=value3&orange=value4&grey=value5&black=value6**

Facts:

random.php - The filename is random, only the ".php?" is fixed

I have about 10 colors defined as parameters

No specific order to the colors - .php?blue=[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}

Can be just 2 colors as parameters, or all the 10, but I want to match on all GET requests, multiple parameters are joined with \&

Values are always between 1-20 and with alphanumerical - .php?blue=[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}

How would you approach this?

Comment: Look at tags. @Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
[^\s/?]+\.php\?((?:blue|orange|red|black)=[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20})(?:&(?1)){1,9}(?:$|#.*)
```

*(complete with the colours you want)*

`(?1)` is a reference to the first capture group subpattern.

I added a support for an eventual anchor part `#.*`. Feel free to remove it if you don't need or want it.

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot of help. Do you think it would be possible to capture different values for every color not 1-20 for every color? Blue = 1-5, Orange = 2-8, Red = 3-6, Black = 7-9

Comment: @SyntycheAckerley: Not sure to fully understand what you ask, but perhaps there's something to do with the [R snort modifier](http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node32.html#SECTION004522000000000000000) with successive patterns

Comment: I'm just interested whether you can specify different values for each color, and not 1-20 for all. Like blue is always between 1-5 characters and so on...

Comment: Yes, in this case put each kind of value in the alternation with its color instead of writing `=[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}` in factor.